# Better way to create an ordered array from priorityQueue in Java

Tags: java

I can of course do the following:

```
        PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(100, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
                return Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(y);
            }
        });
        ...//add some elements to q
        int[] arr = new int[q.size()];
        int i = 0;
        while (q.size() != 0) {
            arr[i++] = q.remove();
        }
```

But this approach emptied the queue which I want to keep. I know I could have sorted using that comparator (of course when it is not as trivial as above) to get this array, but I will have to create an array first, then copy elements from the queue to the array, then sort the array.

Is there any better approach? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should define 'better approach'.  faster? more elegant? shorter code? more space efficient? ...?

Comment: @amit: Yes, all of what you said, if you can provide any of them. Of course, I will choose the best one as the answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

From the Javadocs for `PriorityQueue`:

> This class and its iterator implement all of the optional methods of
>   the `Collection` and `Iterator` interfaces. The `Iterator` provided in
>   method `iterator()` is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the
>   priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal,
>   consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.

Create the array, then sort it. It's the prescribed way.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just empty a copy of the original queue?

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> temp = new PriorityQueue<Integer>( q );
int[] arr = new int[ q.size() ];

int i = 0;
while ( !temp.isEmpty() ) {
    arr[ i ] = temp.remove().intValue();
    i++;
}
```

Just as you did, but on a new queue. I think the cost of copying a priority queue is `O(n)`. Or it should, at least. Emptying the queue is `O(n log n)`, so the final cost is `O(n log n)`, just as getting an array then sorting it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Queue extends Collection, you should be able to iterate iver it.

for (Integer iq: queue)
  arr[i++] = iq;

Hmm, if @amit is right that PriorityQueue doest guarantee iterating in order, this wont work.

**Yet another Edit follows...**

Many of us learned that PriorityQueue doesn't iterate in order.  Which is because PriorityQueue only partially sorts the elements, it mainly tracks the head element (the least).

One proposal to preserve the original PriorityQueue is to make a copy, and take/drain from the copy.  The other is to make a List from the contents (since you know the exact size, I think an ArrayList is most appropriate) and explicitly sort the List.

My guess is that the List would be faster.  We know that it is O(n log(n)).  Now, the PriorityQueue javadocs say that adds and removes are O(log(n)).  And you would be calling them N times, so, in theory, the PriorityQueue is also O(n log(n)).

However, if using a PriorityQueue were actually faster than a sort for this common use case, iterating over an ordered list, I think I would have seen many "performance tips" articles saying "Use a PriorityQueue instead of Collections.sort()."  Which I haven't.  Have I missed them?

Anyway, the OP could try both and report back.  It would be, to me, a fascinating and useful discovery if a PriorityQueue were faster than sorting a List.

**I did some testing on 1 million random Integers**.  The sorted ArrayList was roughly 2 times faster than draining from a PriorityQueue on my ancient 7 year old desktop, JDK6.  Code follows.

```
public class StackOverflow2 {

   ArrayList<Integer> generateRandomList(int count, int seed) {
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(count);
      Random random = new Random();
      random.setSeed(seed);
      for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
         list.add(Integer.valueOf(random.nextInt()));

      return list;
   }

   long usePriorityQueue(ArrayList<Integer> inList) {
      long total = 0;
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

      PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(inList);
      while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
         total += pq.remove();  // do something so HotSpot doesn't optimize this away...
      }

      long totaltime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
      System.out.println("usePriorityQueue  totaltime = " + totaltime);
      return total;
   }

   long useArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> inList) {
      long total = 0;
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(inList);
      Collections.sort(list);
      for (Integer iii : list) {
         total += iii;  // do something
      }

      long totaltime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
      System.out.println("useArrayList  totaltime = " + totaltime);
      return total;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      StackOverflow2 so2 = new StackOverflow2();
      ArrayList<Integer> randoms = so2.generateRandomList(1000000, 123456);

      for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
         long upq = so2.usePriorityQueue(randoms);
         long ual = so2.useArrayList(randoms);
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: it won't be sorted. `PriorityQueue` doesn't guarantee iterating in order

Comment: exactly as amit said! remove or modify your answer before I shall downvote. :)

Comment: This answer addresses the element of wether it is faster to sort the toArray() results or to remove() all elements sequentally which is the only thing we can base the better solution on.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinkedList` as an intermediate collection. Its constructor adds elements in the order specified by the provided collection and its `toArray(T[] arr)` method preserves the list ordering.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(100, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        return Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(y);
    }
});

/* ...elided, add items... */

List<Integer> integers = new LinkedList<Integer>(q);
Integer[] orderedIntegerArray = integers.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Comment: it won't be sorted as well. the iterator of `PriorityQueue` only guarantees the first element will be the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want shorted code, you can always just use [toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) and [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
Integer[] arr = q.toArray(new Integer[1]);
Arrays.sort(arr,q.comparator());
```

**EDIT:** You will need to send the same Comparator to sort() if you don't use natural ordering [fixed the second line in the code sample]

Comment: @QiangLi: It is a parameter to `toArray()`, it will make `toArray()` instantiate a new array [assuming the parameter array is not big enough], and make return the new array. you could also use `Integer[] arr = q.toArray(new Integer[q.size()]);` if you don't want to instantiate the extra array.

Comment: BTW, this is what I described in the question the alternative approach. :)

Comment: @amit  he wants an int[], not Integer[]

Comment: @user949300: the OP asks for an "Ordered array", not an "Ordered array of primitives".

Comment: Can't you just use Collections.sort?

Comment: @AmirAfghani: [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) taks a `List` as an argument, and `PriorityQueue` is not a `List`.

Comment: @amit: if I do want to have int[] rather than Integer[], any way to make it work rather than loop over the array to assign values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList and then use binary search to find the position where the item is put. Thus the insertion is ordered

```
private List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();            

while (q.size() != 0) {
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(items, q.remove());
    if (index >= 0) {
        index++;
    } else {
        index = -(index + 1);
    }
    items.add(index, q.remove);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the iterator loop to iterate over a queue.

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = q.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    arr[i++] = iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: it won't be sorted. `PriorityQueue` doesn't guarantee iterating in order

Comment: He can use `Arrays.sort()` afterwards. This is just one of many options how to handle his problem.